# C#, for a Bitmap file, how can I know when I am using reference or creating a duplicate?

Tags: c#, bitmap

Suppose I have got a

```
Bitmap bt = new Bitmap("test.PNG");
```

What I want to know is that I need an example to show when I have created a duplicate of this "bt" and when I am using this "bt" as a reference.

Can someone give me a few line of sample codes to explain it please?

Thanks a lot.

thanks for all of your reply, I understand the theory of by value and by reference. I just want to see an example of each.for example

```
bt.Clone();
```

the Clone, does it create a duplicate of this bt object?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It is difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Hi, I have just added some explanation, hope it helps.

Comment: You should just read the difference of by value and by reference.

Comment: Classes are passed by reference, structs are passed by value. Bitmap is a class. If you still have more questions, I suggest you do some googling on this subject, and find out how these things work in C#.

Comment: @Chiel92 Yes and no. Reference types are also "copy by value". That is, the value of the reference is copied.. not the data it references.

Comment: Bitmap.Clone() creates a *shallow* copy.  A new Bitmap object but uses the same pixel data and keeps the same lock on the file.  A deep copy requires the Bitmap(Image) constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
var bt = new Bitmap("test.PNG");
```

then

```
var bt2 = bt; 
// bt and bt2 are the same object
```

then

```
var bt3 = bt.Clone(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bt.Size), bt.PixelFormat); 
// bt3 is a different object if you modify bt3, bt does not changes
```